# Amazon S3 Storage

Tags: amazon-s3

I just started to use Amazon S3 storage for storing images uploaded from my app. I am able to access it via a URL:

```
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/.../image.png
```

Does this count as a `GET` request? How am I charge for referencing an image like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am able to access it via a URL. Does this count as a GET request?

If you are pasting this URL in to your browser and pressing go, your browser will make a GET request for this resource, yes.

> How am I charge for referencing an image like this?

AWS charges based on storage and bandwidth. For storage their pricing is based per GB per month. For bandwidth they charge per 1000 requests and per GB of data transferred. Their pricing charts can be found on their documentation:
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/

Answer (score 1):

You are right . It’s a get request.

You pay for every 10k get requests , storage size and of course out bound traffic costs .

Take a look here:
https://blog.cloudability.com/aws-s3-understanding-cloud-storage-costs-to-save/

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, if you want to access a file in Amazon S3 the URL needs to be something like:

`bucketname.s3.region.amazonaws.com/foldername/image.png`

Example: `my-awesome-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/media/img/dog.png`

Don't forget to set the object to public.

Inside S3 if you click on the object will you see a field called: Object URL. That's the object's web address.